# select a class which have additional class

Tags: jquery

```
<div class='m1 about'>About</div>
<div class='m1 contact'>Contact</div>

<div class="sw about"></div>
<div class='sw contact'></div>
```

I need:
if `m1 about` is clicked - `sw about` is selected
If `m1 contact` is clicked - `sw contact` is selected

My try

```
$(".m1").click(function(){
    var a = $(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1];
    $(".sw").hasClass(a).slideDown("slow");
});
```

Doesn't work.

Comment: Should have worked, unless the click is binded before the DOM is created. Is your `$(".m1").click()` inside `$(document).ready(function{})`? and are the divs loaded along with page load?

Comment: dirty way `$(".sw." + a).slideDown("slow");` hasClass returns boolean

Comment: @marathonman, EXCELLENT ! Why dirty way ? Please place this as answer.

Comment: @marathonman I also don't think this is dirty. @bonaca: getting the `class` attribute string, splitting it and using the Nth element is not safe, since the order might get changed. Your code would be fine if you'd replace `hasClass()` (return true if class is present) by `filter()` (reduce set of matched elements by filtering them with the specified selector).

Comment: @try-catch-finally, you're right about filtering, but how do you mean `splitting it and using the Nth element is not safe, since the order might get changed`. Order of what? Classes? How it can be changed?

Comment: Yes, the order. You might do `toggleClass()` and jQuery will remove that string from the `class` attribute value string or add it (to the end) or you might `addClass()` some other class. This might not matter in your current case, but you should keep that in mind. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vm7aH/6/

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".m1").click(function () {
        var a = $(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1];
        if ($(".sw").hasClass(a)) {
            alert(".sw." + a);
            $(".sw" + a).slideDown("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In this case both `sw contact` and `sw about` are slided.

Comment: it's ok, but `$(".sw." + a).slideDown("slow");` is enough. There is no need for `if...`

Answer (score 1):

Change to this:

**js**

```
$(".m1").click(function(){
    var a = $(this).attr("class").split(' ')[1];
    if($(".sw").hasClass(a))
        $(".sw").slideDown("slow");
});
```

jquery `hasClass` returns bool.

[hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

Comment: In this case both `sw contact` and `sw about` are slided

Comment: you want only class `.sw`?

Answer (score 1):

While a little different in terms of the HTML, here's how I would do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lhfz7/3/

```
<div class='m1' data-target-class='about'>About</div>
<div class='m1' data-target-class='contact'>Contact</div>

<div class="sw about"></div>
<div class='sw contact'></div>
```

---

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {

    $(".m1").click(function(){
        console.log("hi")
        var targetClass = $(this).data("target-class")
        var target = $("."+targetClass)
        target.text("Selected")
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

While you've already accepted an answer, I thought I'd offer an alternative approach:

```
// bind the click event-handler:
$('.m1').click(function(){
    // create a string starting with '.', and then join the class-names (from
    // the classList) together with '.', replacing the 'm1' class-name with 'sw':
    $('.' + [].join.call(this.classList,'.').replace('m1','sw'))
    // toggling the display of the found element(s) with a slide down/up:
    .slideToggle(300);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LzqTD/1/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) <sup>*[compatibility](http://caniuse.com/classlist)*</sup>.
  - [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
- jQuery:

  - [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
  - [`slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/).